# XCode Source Control error

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I'm new to source control. I was using XCode embedded source control for my project since the very start of it. And suddenly it says

```
    *** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'NKorotkov@Nikolays-Mini.(none)')
```

and `File is unversioned` next to any file I try to commit. It seems like for some reason it lost my name and email. If I understand correctly I have to run those two commands in terminal to re-enter info, but I'm afraid if I won't be equal to previous info all my commi history will be messed up. How do I know what username was used before?

**UPDATE**

Answering to a comment here's contents of .gitconfig file

```
[filter "media"]
   clean = git media clean %f
   smudge = git media smudge %f
   required = true
[user]
   name = NKorotkov
```

Comment: Can you past the content of your `.gitconfig` file

Comment: @MrMins not sure where to find it. I tried ~/.gitconfig but it says Permission denied

Comment: "it says Permission denied"  This sounds more like the reason you are getting this error.  No file in `~` should have permission errors, so you've broken your filesystem somehow.

Comment: Seems like only email was missing, I ran `git config --global user.email "you@example.com"` with my email and commit worked. Not sure why this happened in the first place. Wonder if it has something to do with the yesterdays OS X update.

Comment: Try checking your .git directory (It's a hidden directory, then, first you need allow the hidden folders with: `com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` in your terminal)